# I am trying to use a dynamic query in an apex class to get the profiles list

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

```
select id, name, KTDO1__Candidate_Profile__r.Name
from KTDO1__Skill_Set_Experience__c
where Name ="Java" and KTDO1__SkillSet_Experience__c = "3 Yrs"
```

When I try to run this query, I get:

> System.QueryException: line 1:96 no viable alternative at character '"'

Can anyone help me with what's wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to escape quotes, rewrite your query as below :

```
String qry = 'SELECT id,name,KTDO1__Candidate_Profile__r.Name from KTDO1__Skill_Set_Experience__c where Name =\'Java\' and KTDO1__SkillSet_Experience__c = \'3 Yrs\' ';

List<KTDO1__Skill_Set_Experience__c> lst = Datbase.query(qry);
```

Or rather than passing values directly in SOQL pass variables and bind them like below

```
String myTestString = 'TestName';
List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM MyCustomObject__c WHERE Name = :myTestString');
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked